# Is it possible to cluster markers based on city name in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, clustering

I have a requirement to display all the customers in map. Since the customer list is too large it looks messy when I place markers.

I have tried the marker cluster functionality but it groups based on distance and that's not what I prefer.

Is there a way to cluster markers based on city names or custom logic??